# magento 2 catalog_product_save_before unable to save product but keeps loading

Tags: php, magento, events, magento2, magento-2.3

I'm trying to save the product in the observer of event `catalog_product_save_before`, but somehow the admin panel is just loading, it's not saving the product.

Can anyone please suggest the solution for this?

```php
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); // you will get product object
        $_sku = $_product->getSku(); // for sku
        $_product->setSku("testNew1");
        $_product->save();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach will cause a loop. Because the catalog_product_save_before is dispatched before every product save. And in this observer you do `$_product->save();` which again will dispatch this event and come in this observer where the `save()` method is called again, etc.

As you get the `$product` in the observer before its save, it should just work to adjust the product object and it will be saved afterwards.

So remove the line `$_product->save();` and it should work fine.